# How to Open Local File in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

i have some code that looks like this

```
function main9Click(event:MouseEvent):void { 

var main9URL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("N:\ICT\Nationals\Unit 2\Pages\Cars");

navigateToURL(main9URL, "_self"); 

}

mainBtn6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, main9Click);
```

I need to make it open so when you click on that button it opens the file

Cheers
Sean

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a relative path. im not sure that flash will like opening things on the hard drive anyway due to security policy. think about researching Air which is more for desktop applications.